# How to set wallpaper in windows 10 using Python 3.6?

Tags: python, windows-10, ctypes

I have seen examples from stack overflow but I am unable to set background of my windows 10 desktop also when I run that program my background changes to black can anyone tell how to set background using python3.6
or tell me what is the error in my code

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, 'image.jpg', 3)
```

Comment: try with an absolute path?

Comment: Please explain with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "c:\\path\\to\\image.jpg" , 0)
```